# Dynamic nested object prop validation - react

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm having trouble on working out a nice way to validate this structure

I've seen suggestions on flattening data like this, but it seems like this is the best way to store this information, as it allows instant access via a item ID / a combo of item ID + store ID.

The data looks like this

```
let data = {
    "itemid1" : {
        "store1" : {
            stockNow: 2,
            stockLater : 15,
            stockDate : "4 days"
        },
        "store2" : {
            stockNow : 2,
            stockLater : 10,
            stockDate : "4 days"
        },
        "store3" : {
            stockNow : 4,
            stockLater : 15,
            stockDate : "4 days"
        },
    },
    "itemid2" : {
        "store1" : {
            stockNow: 2,
            stockLater : 15,
            stockDate : "4 days"
        },
        "store2" : {
            stockNow : 2,
            stockLater : 10,
            stockDate : "4 days"
        },
        "store3" : {
            stockNow : 4,
            stockLater : 15,
            stockDate : "4 days"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: You might consider reducing the duplication by having two props: `stores` is a list of the store objects and `data` has a list of store ids for each item id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this:

EDIT: Didn't notice the itemID part.

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.objectOf(
        PropTypes.objectOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
                stockNow: PropTypes.number,
                stockLater: PropTypes.number,
                stockDate: PropTypes.string,
            })
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Oh I actually had it then, Makes sense now I guess after I read it twice :), thanks